# C# Agregar elementos a archivo XML

Tags: c#

estoy necesitando agregar elementos a un archivo XML el cual ya tiene muchos nodos (asi creo que se llama)

Por ejempolo

```
<1>
<2>
<3>
<4>
<5>
<6>
<7>
<8>
<9>
<10>
<Rows>
<Row>
//HERE
</Row>
 </Rows>
</1>
</2>
</3>
</4>
</5>
</6>
</7>
</8>
</9>
</10>
```

Yo necesito agregar elementos dentro de Row, no tengo un codigo base porque probe muchas veces y no tuve exito.

Comment: esyas seguro que ese xml es valido? porque lo esta raro, no veo que tenga un nodo root

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione. En "Rows" va el Subnodo

```
 private static void save(string a, string b, string c)
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("asdf.xml");
            var sub = new XElement("Row",
                           new XElement("a", a),
                           new XElement("b", b),
                           new XElement("c", c));

            xDoc.Root.Element("Rows").Add(sub);
            xDoc.Save("asdf.xml");
        }
```

Comment: Recuerda marcar tu propia respuesta como solución, saludos.

Comment: No me deja , tengo que esperar 48 horas. Por eso no lo hice